# What is 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper' in Facebook prophet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, facebook-prophet

I'm solving one time series problem with facebook prophet,in which i'm not able to understand what is
'trend','yhat_lower','yhat_upper','trend_lower','trend_upper','additive_terms','additive_terms_lower','additive_terms_upper','multiplicative_terms','multiplicative_terms_lower','multiplicative_terms_upper'
 which comes after the prediction.

Thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Quick Start](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html):

> The `predict` method will assign each row in `future` a predicted value which it names `yhat`. If you pass in historical dates, it will provide an in-sample fit. The `forecast` object here is a new dataframe that includes a column `yhat` with the forecast, as well as columns for components and uncertainty intervals.

Thus

- `yhat`: forecast
- `yhat_lower`, `yhat_upper`: uncertainty interval

Comment: I have a question, my width is set at 0.80 but my yhat lower and upper are the same value.